# Establishing parent-child relationship using a non-primary key field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping, parent-child

I am trying to establish a parent child relationship in a table with the `joinColumn` as a field which is not the Id (primary key) of the table. If the `@onetomany` and `@manytoone` is used with `joinColumn` as primary key , it works. it does the loading of child objects as expected . But the children are not loaded with the similar code in case of non-primary key is given as the `joinColumn` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a `referencedColumnName` in joinColumn where you can specify a different column than the primary key column